# How to copy features and attributes to another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to copy features from a shapefile layer into a PostgreSQL database layer. There occurs a problem if I do so. Some attribute name lengths of the PostGIS layer are above 10, so I can't create the same name in the shapefile attribute table. Let's say I have the attribute name :"network operator" in the db layer and create the name in the shp file too, then I got "network ope" and it does not recognise that the values from this field need to be copied to the network operator field.

Comment: If you are copying " from an shapefile layer into a postgres database layer" then teh 10-character attribute length in the shapefile shouldn't be a problem. Copying *the other way* might be troublesome though. Try it, what happens? Error message? Are the names contracted?

Comment: Yes the names are contracted. Lets say I have the attribute name :"network operator" in the db layer and create the name in the shp file too, then I got "network ope" and it does not recognise that the values from this field need to be copied to the network operator field.

Comment: Yes but you say you are copying *from* a shapefile *to*  a PostGIS layer. The contraction happens when going in the other direction. Are you actually trying to keep two spatial data sets - a shapefile and a PostGIS layer - in sync?

Comment: Your example isn't valid, since field names in shapefile are forbidden from having a space in them -- Valid uppercase SQL identifiers only, with a leading uppercase alpha, and zero or more uppercase alphanumeric or underscore.

Comment: no this was just an example, I translated my actual names to english in my language it has no space. I converted the shapefile now to a geopackage and it works now. Thanks for your time